# AngularJS UI Not updating after $.ajax Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to modify the example at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576246/A-Shopping-Cart-Application-Built-with-AngularJS

I've implemented a new payment service in the example to call a Json method on my server which works fine, but when I call the method clearItems(); to remove the items from the cart on success it removes the items as expected in the background (as I can see from refreshing the page and the cart it empty) - my problem is that it does not clear the cart in the UI (without refreshing)

If I call this.clearItems(); after the Json call it clears the cart items in the UI as expected, but this is not what I requiquire as I only want to clear the items after success.

Can anyone suggest how I can get this to work?

My Json call is listed below

```
  var me = this;
//this.clearCart = clearCart == null || clearCart;
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: '/pos/JsonCashPayment',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(this.items),
    success: function (data) {
        me.clearItems();
        alert('success function called');
        // Do something with the returned data
        // This can be any data
    }
});

//this.clearItems();
```

Thanks

Mark

**EDIT - Problems running $http**

Further to the advice form marck I understand that to do this I need to use $http instead of $json. The problem with doing this is that I need to do this in the shoppingCart.js class  (as part of the payments section) which is attached to the controller via app.js (code below). When I try this though I get a JS error that $http doesn't exist.

Is there a way to use $http from the shoppingCart.js class?

**app.js**

```
var storeApp = angular.module('AngularStore', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/store', {
      templateUrl: 'POS/store',
    controller: storeController 
  }).
  when('/products/:productSku', {
      templateUrl: 'POS/product',
    controller: storeController
  }).
  when('/cart', {
      templateUrl: 'POS/shoppingCart',
    controller: storeController
  }).
  otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/store'
  });
}]);

// create a data service that provides a store and a shopping cart that
// will be shared by all views (instead of creating fresh ones for each view).
storeApp.factory("DataService", function ($http) {

// create store
var myStore = new store($http);

// create shopping cart
var myCart = new shoppingCart("AngularStore");
```

**controller.js**

```
function storeController($scope, $http, $routeParams, DataService) {

// get store and cart from service
$scope.store = DataService.store;
$scope.cart = DataService.cart;
```

**shoppingCart.js**

```
function shoppingCart(cartName) {
this.cartName = cartName;
this.clearCart = false;
this.checkoutParameters = {};
this.items = [];

// load items from local storage when initializing
this.loadItems();

// save items to local storage when unloading
var self = this;
$(window).unload(function () {
    if (self.clearCart) {
        self.clearItems();
    }
    self.saveItems();
    self.clearCart = false;
    });
}

shoppingCart.prototype.checkoutCash = function (parms, clearCart, $scope, $http) {

// Need to be able to run $http here
$http({
    url: '/pos/JsonCashPayment',
    method: "POST",
    data: this.items,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

});   

}
```

Comment: Please use the angular contructs $resource or $http. Else you would need to tell Angular on model update using `$scope.$apply()` method.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? Can that be done from the shoppingCart.js file which is not the controller? Can I access $resource or $http from that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your approach work, you need to inject $http into your controller, then pass it further to the function you've defined in shoppingcart.js, like so in controller.js:

```
'use strict';

// the storeController contains two objects:
// - store: contains the product list
// - cart: the shopping cart object
function storeController($scope, $routeParams, DataService, $http) {

    // get store and cart from service
    $scope.store = DataService.store;
    $scope.cart = DataService.cart;

    // use routing to pick the selected product
    if ($routeParams.productSku != null) {
        $scope.product = $scope.store.getProduct($routeParams.productSku);
    }

   $scope.cart.checkoutCash('parms', 'clearCart', $scope, $http);

}
```

Obviously, the first two arguments I sent to checkoutCash are filler and need to be replaced with more appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks for your help, my problem is the controller has the two modules shoppingCart.js and store.js which are referenced from the controller (you can see this in the sample project with the link in the question), and if I try to use $http or $resource I get a JS undefined error.

Is there a way to run $http or $resource from these subs files?

Comment: Are you injecting $http or $resource (whichever you decide to use) into the controller you've inserted your code into? You need to do this from within your AngularJS app module, and you can only do this from within the external .js files if Angular has been bootstrapped and you're adding another component (e.g. controller, service, or directive) to the running module.

Comment: Hi

I am injecting $http into the controller, problem appears to be shoppingcart.js is a separate js class that's added in the DataService in the example. The injected $http does not appear to be recognised at that level. Is there a way to use $http at the js file level?

Comment: I've updated the question to show where $http is falling over

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you run into more issues like this, you might consider restructuring the application a bit to help keep your AngularJS vs. external code clearly segmented, but this solution should work as a quick fix.